# Backand - Add a default value, after object is created

Tags: database, sdk, default, backand

In Backand, after I've created an object and have data for it in the database, I'd like to go back and add a default value for a field I overlooked. In the GUI, there appears to be a field for this: `Objects > users (the users object I created)`, but it's greyed out and I can't figure out how to use it.

[image: The default value field is greyed out...]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding default value is done in the Model. From the UI you can edit the field and provide default value or in the JSON Model you add this tag:

> "defaultValue": 100

The field object look like this:

> "price": {
>      "type": "float",
>      "defaultValue": 100
>      }